# How to insert date and time in oracle sql database?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
pdate date,  
)/



INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(TO_DATE('02-10-01','dd-mm-yyyy'));
```

Comment: Aside from providing a 2-digit year with a 4-digit mask (so it will evaluate to 0001-10-02, not 2001-10-02 as you might intend), what problems are you having?

Comment: I'd always use date literals where possible: `insert into table_name (pdate) values (date '2001-10-02');`.

Comment: Or for a date with a time you can use `INSERT INTO table_name (pdate) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2001-10-02 12:34:56');` (and the `TIMESTAMP` data type will be implicitly cast to a `DATE` data type with the same date and time components).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert date in the sql table providing date format('DD/MM/YYYY').
Let's take an example of create a table student which will take first_name , last_name and date_of_birth as it's fields

INSERT INTO student (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth)
VALUES ('Harsh', 'kunkuma', TO_DATE('17/02/1998', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));

We can also use DATE literal instead of TO_DATE.
INSERT INTO student (first_name, last_name, date_of_birth)
VALUES ('Harsh', 'kunkuma', DATE '17/02/1998');

Comment: If you already know the date, there is no need to use a string and convert this with `TO_DATE` to a date. Simply use a date literal instead: `DATE '1998-02-17'`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - _"there is no need to use a string and convert this with TO_DATE"_  Well, with either to_date or with a date literal, you still need to supply the string representation of the date.  I've never seen any advantage of either date literal or to_date over the other.

Comment: @EdStevens: A date literal is just that.  It is parsed with the SQL. `TO_DATE` on the other hand is a function that gets executed when you run the query. So the DBMS has to call the function, which takes some time and can fail when you have a mere typo in the string. Most often this doesn't matter at all, because date literals are mainly used in ad-hoc queries. But it is safer to make it a habit to use date literals. Same with numbers. Dont use '12.3' or 12,3' when it is a number 12.3, because Oracle will have to convert the string at runtime (by silently applying `TO_NUMBER`).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - my objection (actually that word implies stronger meaning than I intend) was focused on "no need to use a string".  Both the to_date function and the use of a date literal require the use of a string representation of the date, so that is not the distinguishing argument for or against either method.   :-)